# Scoping issue with object module

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm creating a reusable module that creates a canvas element and draws a circle in it. I currently structured it like this.

```
var circle = (function () {
  return {
    init: function (el) {
      this.el = el

    },

   start: function () {

   }

  }
})()
```

and to start it:

```
for (var i = links.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   circle.init(links[i])
}
```

The problem that I'm facing is that for each element I pass to the module the variables that are bound to 'this' are overwritten.

For example. I have added event listeners for mouseenter en leave in orde to animate the line of the circle. this.canvas will be the value of the last created canvas and not the canvas I wanted to animate.

Full code: https://jsfiddle.net/vnLytr4q/

The example speaks for itself. Only the first (or last in the loop) element will animate.

Comment: var that = this; outside the scope?

Comment: `this` is always `circle` in your current code. I don't really understand what you want.

Comment: @appleapple The jsfiddle is included at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only creating one `circle`, and calling `init` on the same object multiple times. You need to call the function multiple times. Also known as a [constructor function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp).

See the following updated code:

```
var circle = function (el) {
  return {
    init: function () {
      this.el = el

      this.bounds = 0

      this.size = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        radius: 0
      }

      this.angle = {
        start: -0.5,
        end: -0.5
      }

      this.start()
    },

    start: function () {
      this.addListeners()
      this.createCanvas()
      this.setBounds()
      this.draw()
    },

    addListeners: function () {
      this.el.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.onEnter.bind(this))
      this.el.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.onLeave.bind(this))

      window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize.bind(this))
    },

    createCanvas: function () {
      this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
      this.el.appendChild(this.canvas)

      this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d')
    },

    setBounds: function () {
      this.bounds = this.el.getBoundingClientRect()

      this.canvas.style.height = this.bounds.height + 'px'
      this.canvas.style.width = this.bounds.width + 'px'

      this.canvas.height = this.bounds.height * 2
      this.canvas.width = this.bounds.width * 2

      this.size = {
        x: this.canvas.width / 2,
        y: this.canvas.height / 2,
        radius: this.canvas.height / 2
      }
    },

    onEnter: function (e) {
      TweenMax.to(this.angle, 1, {
        end: 3.5,
        start: 1.5,
        onUpdate: this.draw.bind(this),
        ease: Power2.easeOut
      })
    },

    onLeave: function () {
      TweenMax.to(this.angle, 1, {
        end: -0.5,
        start: -0.5,
        onUpdate: this.draw.bind(this),
        ease: Power2.easeOut
      })
    },

    onResize: function () {
      this.setBounds()
      this.draw()
    },

    draw: function () {
      const { x, y, radius } = this.size
      const { start, end } = this.angle

      this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height)

      this.ctx.beginPath()
      this.ctx.arc(x, y, radius - 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
      this.ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)'
      this.ctx.lineWidth = 3
      this.ctx.stroke()

      this.ctx.beginPath()
      this.ctx.arc(x, y, radius - 2, start * Math.PI, end * Math.PI)
      this.ctx.strokeStyle = '#ffffff'
      this.ctx.lineWidth = 3
      this.ctx.stroke()
    }
  }
} // Don't execute the function here

var page = {
  init: function () {
    // get all links
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('.js-button')

    for (var i = links.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      circle(links[i]).init() // Execute the function whenever you're creating a new circle
    }
  }
}

page.init()
```